# Could we allow bold and italics in question titles?

Tags: feature-request, title

Well, could we? At first thought it seems nice. Has this been discussed before?

Comment: *It seems nice* doesn't sound like a compelling reason.

Comment: People could use this to "scream" a question. It would not be fun.

Comment: No because the entire front page of SO would be flooded with: ***PLZ HALP URGANT PLLLLLLLLLZZ***

Comment: @Mysticial - but that's fine.  We could use a script to detect the annoying font style and auto downCloseVote all such questions.

Answer (score 6):

People would use this to "scream" questions, it has been suggested and denied before. As @Mysticial said, the front page of popular sites would be flooded with

> ***PLZ H3LP URG4NT PLLLLLZZZZZZZZZZ!!!***

It would damage the content of the sites and essentially lead to harder and more moderaton... ect.

Comment: Whould these font styles not make it easier to detect the rubbish questions?

Comment: @MartinJames No, it would just create more of them.

Comment: @MartinJames not really, people would figure it out and game it to prevent and go under the radar.

Answer (score 5):

If anything, I'd rather have `code formatting` in titles.

People are trying to do that  [quite often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748358/iterator-invalidation-by-stdstringbegin-stdstringend), failing spectacularly. I catch myself on trying to do that all the time (which is also, incidentally, the case with GitHub's issue titles).

Comment: Now that would be helpfull!